# Is it preferable to convert an Observable to a Promise when we don't need extra features of Observables?

Tags: angular, promise, observable

There is a situation in which I don't need special and extra features of `Observables` such as stream of async calls, cancellation etc..Is it good practice to convert `Observable` to `Promise`. I mean to say is are there any performance improvements, any other advantages or better to use `Observable` only. Please help me understand this.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say no. If you already have an observable, I'm pretty sure there is no gain by converting it to a Promise. Rather the opposite.

Comment: In some cases I saw converting `observable` to `promise` e.g. using `.toPromise()` in angular. Why?

Comment: If you need to call a method or function that expects a Promise, you can't pass an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, its a matter of code design and usage. If your application design already depends on Observables in some cases then there is no need to introduce a second way of handling async operations.

In a team development scenario at least, decisions like this make things simpler.